# AWS: None of the Instances are sending data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to set up an Elastic Beanstalk application with Amazon Web Services however I'm receiving a load of errors with the message `None of the instances are sending data`. I've tried deleting the Elastic Beanstalk Application and the EC2 instance several times with the sample application and trying again but I get the same error.

I also tried uploading a flask application with AWS Elastic Beanstalk command line tools but then I received the error below:

```
Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Severe. 100.0 % of the requests to the ELB are failing with HTTP 5xx. Insufficient request rate (0.5 requests/min) to determine application health (7 minutes ago). ELB health is failing or not available for all instances. None of the instances are sending data
```

Why do I get this error and how do I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You are using [Enhanced Health Monitoring](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elastic-beanstalk-update-enhanced-application-health-monitoring/).
With enhanced health monitoring an [agent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced.html#health-enhanced-agent) installed on your EC2 instance monitors vital system and application level health metrics and sends them directly to Elastic Beanstalk.

When you see an error message like "None of the instances are sending data", it means either the agent on the instance has crashed or it is unable to post data to Elastic Beanstalk due to networking error or some other error.

For debugging this, I would recommend downloading "Full logs" from the AWS console. You can follow the instructions for getting logs in the section "Downloading Bundle Logs from Elastic Beanstalk Console" [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html).
If you are unable to download logs using the console for any reason you can also ssh to the instance and look at the logs in `/var/log`.

You will find logs for the health agent in `/var/log/healthd/daemon.log`.
Additional logs useful for this situation are `/var/log/cfn-init.log`, `/var/log/eb-cfn-init.log` and `/var/log/eb-activity.log`. Can you look at the logs and give more details of the errors you see?
This should hopefully give you more details regarding the error "None of the instances are sending data".

Regarding other health "causes" you are seeing:

- **Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Severe** - This is because initially your environment health status is *Pending*. If the instances do not go healthy within grace period health status transitions to *Severe*. In your case since none of the instances is healthy / sending data, the health transitioned to Severe.
- **100.0 % of the requests to the ELB are failing with HTTP 5xx. Insufficient request rate (0.5 requests/min) to determine application health (7 minutes ago).**
  Elastic Beanstalk monitors other resources in addition to your EC2 instances when using enhanced health monitoring. For example, it monitors cloudwatch metrics for your ELB. This error means that all requests sent to your environment CNAME/load balancer are failing with HTTP 5xx errors. At the same time the request rate is very low only 0.5 requests per minute, so this indicates that even though all requests are failing, the request rate is pretty low. "7 minutes ago" means that information about ELB metrics is slightly old. Because Elastic Beanstalk monitors cloudwatch metrics every few minutes, so the data can be slightly stale. This is as opposed to health data we get directly from the EC2 instances which is "near real time". In your case since the instances are not sending data the only available source for health is ELB metrics which is delayed by about 7 minutes.
- **ELB health is failing or not available for all instances**
  Elastic Beanstalk is looking at the health of your ELB, i.e. it is checking how many instances are in service behind ELB. In your case either all instances behind ELB are out of service or the health is not available for some other reason. You should double check that your service role is correctly configured. You can read how to configure service role correctly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31978572/161628) or in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles.html). It is possible that your application failed to start.

In your case I would suggest focusing on the first error "None of the instances are sending data". For this you need to look at the logs as outlined above. Let me know what you see in the logs. The agent is started fairly early in the bootstrap process on the instance. So if you see an error like "None of the instances are sending data", it is very likely that bootstrap failed or the agent failed to start for some reason. The logs should tell you more.

Also make sure you are using an instance profile with your environment. Instance profile allows the health agent running on your EC2 instance to authenticate with Elastic Beanstalk. If instance profile is not associated with your environment then the agent will not be able to send data to Elastic Beanstalk. Read more about Instance Profiles with Elastic Beanstalk [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles.html#concepts-roles-instance).

**Update**
One common reason for the health cause "None of the instances are sending data" can be that your instance is in a VPC and your VPC does not allow NTP access. Typical indicator of this problem is the following message in `/var/log/messages: ntpdate: Synchronizing with time server: [FAILED]`. When this happens the clock on your EC2 instance can get out of sync and the data is considered invalid. You should also see a health cause on the instances on the health page on the AWS web console that tells you that instance clock is out-of-sync. The fix is to make sure that your VPC allows access to NTP.

---

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I try to access to logs for my Elastic Beanstalk application like you said and it restarts the EB app and then nothing happens. I'm unable to get the logs at all.

Comment: Another possibility is that you have incorrect VPC configuration so the bootstrap failed. Again if you can ssh to the instance and get the logs you will have details.

Comment: I'm trying to ssh into the EC2 instance, but it times out. `debug1: connect to address 52.17.213.23 port 22: Operation timed out`

Comment: Can you double check your VPC configuration? This strongly suggests that somehow networking is not working correctly on your EC2 instance. Can you also look at the EC2 console logs from the EC2 console. To do this you can follow these steps: 

    1. Open the Amazon EC2 console.

    2. Select the instance.

    3. Choose Actions, then Instance Settings, and then Get System Log.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html

Comment: I've not gone into the VPC before, what am I checking for once I found the VPC configuration? I've also got the system log, would you like to see a copy of it?

Comment: Yes copy of system log will be useful

Comment: Yep confirmed. Initial bootstrap is failing for the instance because the logs show "curl https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-env-resources-eu-west-1/stalks/eb_python_4.0.1/lib/UserDataScript.sh" is failing. Can you double check that the VPC in which your EC2 instance lives has access to internet through an internet gateway? Did you use any special configuration for VPC on your environment?

Comment: I haven't touched the VPC at all. I checked if there was an internet gateway associated with the VPC for my EC2 instance and there was?

Comment: Can you post your question on AWS Forums? https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=86
There you can PM me your instance id and account ID and then we can look at the network configuration.

Comment: Here is the AWS forums question: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=216107

Answer (score 12):

There can be many reasons why the health agent is not able to send any data, so this may not be the answer to your problem, but it was to mine and hopefully can help somebody else:

I got the same error and looking into `/var/log/healthd/daemon.log` the following was repeatedly reported:

```
sending message(s) failed: (Aws::Healthd::Errors::GroupNotFoundException) Group 97c30ca2-5eb5-40af-8f9a-eb3074622172 does not exist
```

This was caused by me making and using an AMI image from an EC2 instance inside an Elastic Beanstalk environment. That is, I created a temporary environment with one instance the same configuration as my production environment, went into the EC2 console and created an image of the instance, terminated the temporary environment, and then created yet another environment using the new custom AMI.

Of course (in hindsight) this meant some settings of the temporary environment were still being used. In this case specifically `/etc/healthd/config.yaml`, resulting in the health agent trying to send messages to a no longer existing health group.

To fix this and make sure there was no other stale configuration around, I instead started a new EC2 instance by hand from the default AMI used in the production environment (find it under the 'Instances' configuration page of your environment), provision that, then create a new image from that and use that image in my new EB environment.

Comment: Hi @sgvd, i am also facing the same issue. Is there a way we can change the group_id in /etc/healthd/config.yaml. Can we find the group_id of new environment and update it there?

Comment: This really saves us. In our scenario, we spawn up the EC2 using an image we created from another environment.

Answer (score 6):

Check if your instance type's RAM is enough for app + os + amazon tooling. We suffered from this for a long time, when we discovered that t2.micro is barely enough for our use cases. The problem went away right after using t2.small (2GB).

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by adding another security group (the default one for my Elastic Beanstalk).

Comment: Added another security group to what, the EC2 instance? It already had an Elastic Beanstalk security group added but it seems to produce two. Does it need to be in both?

Answer (score 3):

It appears my problem was that I didn't associate a public ip address to my instance... after I set it it worked just fine.

Comment: yes.. Load balancer servers need public IP to work

Answer (score 3):

For anyone arriving here in 2022…

After launching a new environment that was identical to a current healthy environment and seeing no data, I raised an AWS Support ticket. I was informed:

> Here, I would like to inform you that recently Elastic Beanstalk introduced new feature called `EnhancedHealthAuthEnabled` to increase security of your environment and help prevent health data spoofing on your behalf and this option will be enabled by default when you create new environment.

> If you use managed policies for your instance profile, this feature is available for your new environment without any further configuration as Elastic Beanstalk instance profile managed policies contain permissions for the `elasticbeanstalk:PutInstanceStatistics` action. However, If you use a custom instance profile instead of a managed policy, your environment might display a No Data health status. This happens because custom instance profile doesn't `PutInstanceStatistics` permission by default and instances aren't authorised for the action that communicates enhanced health data to the service. Hence, your environment health shows Unknown/No data status.

The policy that I needed to attach to my existing EC2 role (as advised by AWS Support) looked like:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ElasticBeanstalkHealthAccess",
      "Action": [
        "elasticbeanstalk:PutInstanceStatistics"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:*:application/*",
        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:*:environment/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Adding this policy to my EC2 role solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you see something like this where you don't get any enhanced metrics, check that you haven't accidentally removed the `conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/healthd.conf` include from your nginx config. This conf adds an machine-read log format that is responsible for reporting that data in EB (see [Enhanced health log format - AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-serverlogs.html)).

[image: no metrics]

Answer (score 1):

I was running an app in elastic beanstalk environment with docker as platform. I got the same error that none of the instances are sending. And I was unable fetch logs as well.
**Rebuilding the environment worked for me.**

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just updated `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` at `Trust Relationships` guide as following:

```json
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just set the Path on load balancing to a URL that response with status code 200, for this only to study environment.

For my real app, I use actuator

Answer (score 0):

My instance profile's IAM Role was lacking `elasticbeanstalk:PutInstanceStatistics` permission.

I found this by looking at `/var/log/healthd/daemon.log` as suggested in one of the other answers.

I had to SSH into the machine directly to discover this, as the Get Logs function itself was failing due to missing S3 Write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a [Worker Tier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html) EB, need to add [this policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles-instance.html):

```
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier
```

Answer (score 0):

The memory problem can be one of the causes, this can be solved changing the instance type, or changing the configuration of the instance to use the Swap (Linux). Later another cause of the instance is offline can be that the instance its in a private subnet, and the AWS Console cant receive the Health data (status No Data). This is a networking issue. To fix this you can add a NAT Gateway in a Public Subnet, and then in the Routes Tables of each private subnet add a route to it.

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue while creating new environment using elastic beanstalk with latest **Amazon Linux 2** platform. I faced this issue because I was attaching the ec2 role which I had created for old environment running Amazon Linux 1.

The solution for this is we need to attach this policy if we are not using managed policy while creating environment.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ElasticBeanstalkHealthAccess",
      "Action": [
        "elasticbeanstalk:PutInstanceStatistics"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:*:application/*",
        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:*:environment/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**NOTE: By default aws attaches this policy if we use aws managed roles.Above solution is only for custom roles.**

**Adding this to custom created role solved the issue for me.**

Answer (score -1):

In My case when i increased my ram or instance type(t2.micro to c5.xlarge) it had resolved.