# INFO: Closed port 22 on ec2 instance security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to SSH into my Elastic Beanstalk instance using the EB CLI  to access my logs however after entering `eb ssh`, I get this:

```
INFO: Attempting to open port 22.
INFO: SSH port 22 open.
ssh: connect to host (IP for the EC2 instance) port 22: Operation timed out
INFO: Closed port 22 on ec2 instance security group.
ERROR: An error occurred while running ssh.
```

I've set the security group of my ec2 instance to allow inbound ssh from anywhere on port 22 however I still get this error.

What's the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Most likely VPC configuration issue assuming yo are referring to the same issue as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32364229/aws-none-of-the-instances-are-sending-data

Answer (score 1):

Place your `.pem` file `~/.ssh` folder, then try `eb ssh`.

As elasticbeanstalk uses codedeploy to deploy your application to ec2 instances you can do direct ssh to AMI EC2 instance. using.

> ssh -i securityKey.pem ec2-user@elasticbeanstalkip