# Access denied while accessing Auto Scaling.... Verify the role Policy (AWS)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I'm trying to migrate a Spring Boot Java application into AWS for the first time and ran into an issue. After reading through some tutorials I have separate Spring profiles and their respective connection properties defined, and a database in AWS's RDS. I then went into Elastic Beanstalk and created an application and an environment, but the environment is displaying a health warning.

This is the warning: Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Warning. Initialization completed 4 seconds ago and took 3 minutes. There are no instances. Access denied while accessing Auto Scaling and Elastic Load Balancing using role "arn:aws:iam::370136948253:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role". Verify the role policy.

So my after finding [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048543/aws-beanstalk-getting-access-denied-while-accessing-auto-scaling-and-err) it seems there's some sort of user role permission issue. I went into the IAM console to attempt to give the service the permissions needed, but am getting tripped up on how to accomplish that. Do I need to define a new role and give it certain permissions? Or do I need to assign permissions to a specific service?

Does anyone have an idea of what I need to do to straighten this out?

Much appreciated!

[Screenshot of environment health warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l9C1.png)

Comment: Go to IAM console, Roles and check what permissions are attached to `aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role` role.

Comment: I checked it out and no permissions were given. I've now given admin access to elasticbeanstalk-service-role. I couldn't figure out a way to "redeploy" the first environment with the new permissions so I made a new one and everything is going smooth. Thank you so much!

Comment: Update: I rebuilt the first environment with the new permissions and it works great as well! Thanks again