# Why is my Elastic Beanstalk environment not responsive

Tags: .net-core, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My .netcore application deploys without error to my elastic beanstalk environment, but in visual studio the status says that the environment is unresponsive.

When I go to check the error on the EB portal, the environment health is red but the "causes" button is disabled, and you can see this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1KSh.png).

I'm running on a Linux 2/2.2.2 server with a default AWS EC2 security group. Environment type is a single instance. I don't have a load balancer configured since it is a small application. When I click on the health, it shows nothing. There are no EC2 instances that are available to select in the health tab. None of the event types in the Events tab show "severe" or "warn", only "info".

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgQbR.png) is an image of the events.

Has anyone ever encountered this error? I would troubleshoot it, but I can't even see what the issues with the health are.

Comment: I rebuilt the environment and the health returned to grey, and I still cannot view the causes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might have solved it - I changed the instance type to load balancing instead of single instance and then I attached two policies to the IAM role policy by following the instructions [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67462371/14633524).